# MySQL на разных страницах сайта в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Как сохранять одно подключение (или одну транзакцию) к MySQL на разных страницах сайта в PHP? Это нужно, когда мы заполняем множество настроек на разных страницах, а потом нам нужно их откатить.

Answer (score 0):

Делать длинные транзакции плохая идея в принципе - с большой долей вероятности будут проблемы с блокировками. На мой взгляд хорошим решением будет настройки хранить в сессии, а записывать в базу уже в одну транзакцию в конце.